# Input box inside a box/table

Tags: java, html

I have an input box called keywords. I want to put this box inside another box. this is my code:

```
<div class="tfirst">
<h3>Keywords</h3>

    <input id="keywords" type="text" size="100" runat="server" title="Keywords" />

</div>
<div class="tsecond" style="visibility:hidden">
    <h3>Cost</h3>
    <ul>
    <li><input id="chkOnlyFree" type="checkbox" /><label for="chkOnlyFree">Only show images having free required materials</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tthird">  
    <h3>Genders</h3>
    <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to put the 1st Div inside a box.

Comment: what's a _box_? maybe fieldset?

Comment: Wow!  There was no need to indent that to the other hemisphere of Earth.

Comment: And now I can see it..  Sorry, where's the 'Java'?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a `table` instead of `div` elements.